# What is equivalent for "Response" method of ASP in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, oauth, httprequest

I am trying to implement oAuth authentication in my desktop application. In a code example I found over the internet is like below. I guess it is ASP.Net code but I'm using VB.Net for my project. The problem is I don't know what is equivalent for `Request` in VB.Net.

```
    If Request("oauth_token") Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox("Nothing")
    Else
        MsgBox("Something")
    End If
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both Request and Response are objects in VB as well as C#:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms524716(v=VS.90).aspx

It's unclear which one you're referring to however; Response or Request?

Comment: At first, thank you for your quick response. To explain further, I would like to do the same thing as the example did while checking if the returning value of Request("oauth_token") is true or false. I just can't figure out with what I can do so in a VB.NET desktop client application.

Comment: Ahh, I missed the desktop piece.  For future reference, VB.net can be used for both web and desktop app development.  Better to say WinForms vs Web, instead of VB.NET vs ASP.NET. Check this link, it might solve your dilemma: http://www.voiceoftech.com/swhitley/index.php/2010/02/twitter-oauth-with-net-for-the-desktop/